# Inferring type of keys in a map (while also typing the values in a map)

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'd like to infer the type of keys from a map.

I can successfully do this:

```js
const componentStyles = {
  button: { color: 'red' },
  heading: { fontSize: 18, lineHeight: 28 },
  body: { fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 },
};

type ComponentName = keyof (typeof componentStyles);
```

And TypeScript will infer that:

```js
type ComponentName = 'button' | 'heading' | 'body';
```

However, I'd also like to enforce the type of values in my map. But when I do this:

```js
interface Style {
  color?: string;
  fontSize?: number;
  lineHeight?: number;
}

const componentStyles: {[key: string]: Style} = {
  button: { color: 'red' },
  heading: { fontSize: 18, lineHeight: 28 },
  body: { fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 },
};

type ComponentName = keyof (typeof componentStyles);
```

Then TypeScript will infer:

```js
type ComponentName = string | number;
```

Is there a way around this? (Without writing out the map keys manually.)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I'd like typescript to infer `type ComponentName = 'button' | 'heading' | 'body';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case I would recommend a helper function that doesn't change the inferred type of `componentStyles` but which will only allow you to make objects with the right property types:

```
const asComponentStyles = <T extends Record<keyof T, Style>>(t: T) => t;
```

This is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function where the type parameter `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be assignable to `Record<keyof T, Style>`.  This is a self-referential constraint (known as [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)) and allows the compiler to verify that the type `T` inferred from calling the function has, for any key in `keyof T`, properties assignable to `Style`.  Let's see it in action:

```
const componentStyles = asComponentStyles({
    button: { color: 'red' },
    heading: { fontSize: 18, lineHeight: 28 },
    body: { fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 },
});

type ComponentName = keyof (typeof componentStyles);
// type ComponentName = "button" | "heading" | "body"
```

This works as you intended.  And let's make sure that it's doing its job of preventing bad `Style` properties:

```
const errorChecking = asComponentStyles({
    okay: { color: 'chartreuse', lineHeight: 123 },
    badColor: { color: 123, lineHeight: 123 }, // error!
    //          ~~~~~ <── 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
    excessPropChecking: { colour: "grey" } // error!
    //   ┌──────────────> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, 
    // but 'colour' does not exist in type 'Style'.
    // Did you mean to write 'color'?
})
```

Also looks good.

---

Note that you might be able to get away with a simpler non-self-referential helper function using an index signature similar to how you're doing it in your question:

```
const asComponentStylesIndex = <T extends { [k: string]: Style }>(t: T) => t;

const componentStylesIndex = asComponentStylesIndex({
    button: { color: 'red' },
    heading: { fontSize: 18, lineHeight: 28 },
    body: { fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 },
}); // okay
```

That works because TypeScript will take an object literal and give it an [implicit index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures).

But I wouldn't recommend this if you are going to be using interface values, since [they are not currently allowed to gain implicit index signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), while the F-bounded version works for interfaces as well as object literals:

```
interface MyComponent {
    foo: Style,
    bar: Style
}
declare const myComponent: MyComponent; // value of an interface type

const works = asComponentStyles(myComponent); // okay
const doesntWork = asComponentStylesIndex(myComponent); // error!
//  ┌───────────────────────────────────> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Index signature is missing in type 'MyComponent'.
```

Not sure if interface-valued things are part of your use case or not.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgJ4BsUG8CwAUMicggPZblQD8AXMgM5hSgDmA3EacjOeKmAAvCPWQgArgFsARtC7FSWUBAASEYGwAWYMZNnyiAXyJEKIZsjiMAwuSkAHfhAGYcjZAF5kAHgAqyBAAHpAgACYeAEoQFFBhPgDWEBjkMMh+ADRobhAAfLkAFGAMfgCUXrnIYApm-JYUjs6u2BAe3tZ2jSAuYOgtjAUEiiQyEmBg-Ay4ZJTUDADkUBBh88hGGdykWhBwYexTvPy9whAMAIwAHFnK3eqaOgwATBdrG8PIMuRhGAd8AifnR7XFR3bTFZCXV7GUo1QiYBwoTpObrgABycCkKG8SRSaSKGARqRmXR6fXcMKIAHpKVUCYj7MieujMV5kAAiUbjfhs5AAH3Z2127B5-I5XwwbNMhHMlmgUGoNm2CAS7FZHQZTV6OQGQx45AScB+yGmFCoUAWCC0cCgLAgEkYEHmwNuGjBgIAzFD3jJdnYzQdTXMIY93c61K6HsHPetkNTAlB5VAAISbEhxngZgB+2ezvkAAKR55DzfRyKCrYAeEDkMBWRiMTQgOAyHBVci0hFF5isEBsPnICThCAwFQrAB0qcCQSQdYACvKHIqYiqewHZhJzey2EsJWtYzS5dQU+904AYUgL54vl7zlRzt7v2YncYA8jIAFYxGvKSBQOBYZBSQ1kH4LAMCYBEEGAGBQISKsAHcQGQBx52gMBgFaLJHxpTki0DddVjCchWnEatJwrGtQHbFB5jJR1x2PGkABFgDCZAUgkf8dgQiZkFg1hIBw2YyxoaEpRlGt1RJZp3AASUHIJWX8SdQgiY1kAAbQSBgu3YABdBgaLWQpwTKCoqlhMTiUZKTWlksJgjVWwNRRLV+ls4JBgnTkJhAVd-SLJYVi9HhBT2FdVL+Y4RHOK5kBucN7nBZ4gtIT5vl+I5BCi4Mw1BSNIXWaEOD3ICDQwKVQG-eAkGQABZDAkU1Y0Jz4ch9JyN4eB9DcaOMIg7IQLBrRQCypHqpyegYOqGuc8y6hrWDqASNpa2m0ltQKUbVvAGFkFqCwawI1pwAAdUWhytpcmS5I2sbJLAHa4wPZMqRpZAzyvD7Pq+i8b3vW8XuQNz5PrNhGzAdcUArf8K3rHtkAo+EqKm8bwHmOipSAA)

Comment: Wow, this is the most awesome answer I've ever received in StackOverflow or anywhere else. Thanks a lot.